# Am I erasing the stack here?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am using gcc on Linux and the below code compiles successfully but not printing the values of variable `i` correctly, if a character is entered once at a time `i` jumps or reduces to 0. I Know I am using `%d` for a `char` at scanf(I was trying to erase the stack). Is this a case of attempt to erase stack or something else ?( I thought if the stack was erased the program would crash).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char c;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        scanf ("%d", &c);
        printf ("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of a program with undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: The relation is you are overwriting the previous value of c on every pass through the loop.

Comment: @Jawsmerc please read the answer of Kerrek carefully.The C standard clearly states that if any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.

Comment: This is a case of undefined behaviour, which can manifest in various ways or not manifest visibly at all. For example, if your compiler decided to put `i` in the register instead of the stack, you would not see the values of `i` change around, but you could find different side-effects. It should be enough to know that you're invoking undefined behaviour, which gcc will happily tell you about if you ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the arguments to `main`, you have an `int` and a `char` on the stack.
Lets assume `sizeof(int) == 4` and only have a look at `i` and `c`.

```
(              int i               )(char c )
[   0   ][   1   ][   2   ][ 3 (&i)][ 4 (&c)]
```

So this is actually your stack layout without `argc` and `*argv`.
With `i` consuming four times more memory than `c` in this case.
The stack grows in the opposite direction, so if you write something bigger than a `char` to `c`, it will write to `[4]` and further to the left, never to the right. So `[5]` will never get written to. Instead you overwrite `[3]`.
For the case where you write an `int` to `c` and `int` is four times bigger than `c`, you'll actually write to `[1][2][3][4]`, just `[0]` will not be overwritten, but 3/4 of the memory for the `int` will be corrupted.

On a big-endian system, the most significant byte of `i` will be stored in `[3]` and therefore get overwritten by this operation. On a little-endian system, the most significant byte is stored in `[0]` and would be preserved. Nonetheless, you corrupt your stack this way.

As ams mentions this is not always true. There could be different alignments for efficiency or because the platform only supports aligned access, leaving gaps between variables. Also a compiler is allowed to do any optimizations as long as it has no visible side-effects as stated by the as-if rule. In this case the variables could perfectly be stored in a register and never be saved on the stack at all. But a lot of other compiler optimizations and platform dependencies can make this way more complex.
So this is only the simplest case without taking platform dependencies and compiler optimizations into account and also seems to be what happens in your special case with maybe some minor differences.

Comment: @foobar Thanks this what I was looking for , that if `scanf` would actually do what its doing in the program or would it truncate the scanned value. But I might be wrong, based on what I have been trying to find out I was thinking `char c` is placed before `int i`  in what you have depicted.

Comment: The size of `c` is only known at compile time. Passing `%d` to `scanf` effectively tells it, that the `sizeof(c)` is the `sizeof(int)`, which is just wrong. Usually your compiled should warn you about that mistake. But `scanf` will just happily write `sizeof(int)` bytes to the memory area pointed to.

Comment: Your picture is wrong.  The address of `c` comes first, the address of `i` comes last.  You can check this with `printf("&i=%u, &c=%u\n", &i, &c)`. The stack grows down, which means that if you declare anothe variable, its address will be before `c`.  But when you fill the stack, it will be filled in the usual direction.  So, in _little endian_ machines, the _least_ significant byte is the one that gets overwritten, and that's why Jaws merc sees always that `i=0`

Comment: This *might* be true on some systems. On other systems what you will get is a crash caused by unaligned memory access. On yet another system it will work perfectly.

Comment: @JuanCespedes thank you, i messed up little- and big-endian. it's corrected.

Comment: @ams this is of course only the simplest case with all the platform dependent rules and compiler optimizations ignored, as this would otherwise be unexplainable. but you're right, that this circumstance should be mentioned.

Comment: @foobar Actually, assuming simple alignment *is* a implementation-dependent assumption.

Comment: @Rhymoid but isn't it also what you'd assume it to be if something like alignment didn't exist?

Comment: @foobar I don't think the C standards allow you to assume anything when it comes to where local variables are stored, let alone how alignment works. I'd have to look it up, though.

Comment: @Rhymoid I know that I'm not allowed to assume anything like that. But it's the most plausible decision made by the compiler for what Jaws merc experiences.

Answer (score 3):

With your `scanf()`, you are inserting a `int` inside a `char`.  One `char` is usually stored using just 1 byte, so your compiler will probably overflow, but it could or not overwrite other values, depending on the alignment of the variables.

If your compiler reserves 1 byte for the `char`, and the memory address of the `int` is just after the address of the `char` (that will probably be the case), then your `scanf()` will just overwrite the first bytes of `i`.  If you are in a *little-endian* machine and you enter values smaller than 256, then `i` will always be 0.

But it can grow larger if you enter a bigger value.  Try entering 256; `i` will become 1.  With 512, `i` will become 2, and so one.

But you are not "erasing the stack", just overwriting some bytes (in fact, you are overwriting `sizeof(int)` bytes; one of them correspond to the `char` and the others will probably be all the bytes in your `int` but one).

If you really want to "erase the stack", you could do something like:

```
#include <string.h>

int
main(void) {
    char c;

    memset(&c, 0, 10000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@foobar has given a very nice description of what one compiler on one architecture happens to do. He(?) also gives an answer to what a hypothetical big-endian compiler/system *might* do.

To be fair, that's probably the most useful answer, but it's still not *correct*.

There is no rule that says the stack must grow in one way or the other (although, much like whether to drive on the left or the right, a choice must be made, and a descending stack *is* most common).

There is no rule that says the compiler must layout the variables on the stack in any particular way. The C standard doesn't care. Not even the official architecture/OS-specific ABI cares a jot about that, as long as the bits necessary for unwinding work. In this case, the compiler could even choose a different scheme for every function in the system (not that it's likely).

All that is certain is that `scanf` will *try* to write something `int`-sized to a `char`, and that this is undefined. **In practice** there are several possible outcomes:

- It works fine, nothing extra is overwritten, and you got lucky. (Perhaps `int` is the same size as `char`, or there was padding in the stack.)
- It overwrites the data following the `char` in memory, whatever that is.
- It overwrites the data just before and/or after the `char`. (This might happen on an architecture where an aligned store instruction disregards the bottom bits of the write address.)
- It crashes with an unaligned access exception.
- It detects the stack scribble, prints a message, and [reports the incident](http://xkcd.com/838/).

Of course, none of this will happen because you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` enabled, and GCC tells you that your scanf format doesn't match your variable types.

Comment: +1 for stating several possibilities of what could happen on different platforms and a more abstract but also more correct explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As **Kerrek SB** commented, the behavior is **undefined**.

As you know, you pass a `char *` to the `scanf` function, but tells the function to treat it like an `int *`.

It *might* (although very unlikely to) overwrite something else on the stack, for example, `i`, the previous stack pointer or the return address.

It *might* just override unused bytes, for example if the compiler uses padding to align the stack.

It *might* cause a crash, for example if the address of `c` is not 4- or 8-byte aligned and the platform requires de-reference of int to be 4- or 8-byte aligned.

And it might do **anything** else.

But the answer is still - anything is possible in such case. The behavior is simply not defined.